# Reading webtable using selenium and python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I need to read the following webtable in the pandas dataframe using selenium and python

part contains column names
I have given the html of the first row as per below

```
Checkbox    Sr.No.   Items    Price    

              1      5         20       
              2      3         50       

<table class="completetbclass" id="1234unique">
        <tbody>
            <th align="left>
                <a id="heaader_id1" >
                    "Sr.No."  ---header name
                    <span id="spantest1"></span>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th align="left>
                <a id="heaader_id2" >
                    Items ---header_name
                    <span id="spantest2"></span>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th align="left>
                <a id="heaader_id3" >
                    Price ----header_name
                    <span id="spantest3"></span>
                </a>
            </th>           
            <tr class="row1" id="2">
                <td align="center" class="tb">
                    <span>
                        <table class="tbclass">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="xyz" id="tyu">
                                        <a id="yu" href="#">
                                            <span>123</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </span>
                </td>
                
                <td align="center" class="tb">
                    <span>
                        <table class="tbclass">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="qrv",qrv_id="ab">
                                        <input value="5" type="text" id="776">
                                        
                                            
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </span>
                </td>
                
                <td align="center" class="tb">
                    <span>
                        <table class="tbclass">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="qrv",qrv_id="24ab">
                                        <input value="20" type="text" id="7778h">
                                        
                                            
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
'''
```

I need to read the above webtable  using selenium and python.I have put the html of the first row.
currently i am trying to read it using pandas dataframe,but I am not able to.Following s the code

```
webtable=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*table[@id="1234unique"]').get_attribute("outerHTML")
df=pd.read_html(webtable}
```

But this code is not working.What is the altenate way to read this webtable in the table in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Without having an actual link to your data (maybe this is an intranet site), I can't test these code samples, but you certainly can.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h8/current/default.htm'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[10]
print(df)


############################################################################


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_population"
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all('table')
print(table)


############################################################################


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = "http://biz.yahoo.com/c/s.html"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "lxml")

alltables = soup.find_all("table")
print(alltables)
```